# Customizing the pagination component ag-grid vue

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

[image]

I will like to customize my ag-grid pagination to look something like this. I read on the documentation about the `:suppressPaginationPanel="true"`, which takes a way the default pagination. How do I proceed. with customizinf after the default panel is gone

Answer (score 0):

According to the ag-grid documentation: **supressPaginationPanel** is a part of the **GridOptions** (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/).

By looking at the code it looks like you directly bind this property to the Vue component like this:

```
<ag-grid-vue :suppressPaginationPanel="true"></ag-grid-vue>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that which takes a way the default pagination panel, just left to add a custom pagination panel like the picture